# Тестирование классов с закрытыми конструкторами

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты

Для тестирования приватных методов Visual Studio предлагает создавать ClassName_Accessor'ы, и если не углубляться, это весьма удобный способ.

Но представим, что у нас есть **класс с закрытым конструктором** и тестируемая функция, принимающая этот класс:

```
public class B
{
    public static void TestMe(A a) { }
}

public class A
{
    internal A() { }
}
```

В чём проблема: на `B.testMe(new A_Accessor())` компилятор выдаёт

> преобразование типа из `A_Accessor` в `A` невозможно.

Что же делать, как же быть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Зачем тестировать закрытые члены классов?
2. Зачем нужен класс с закрытым конструктором?
   Вариант с рефлексией безусловно в юнит-тестировании имеет место быть, но как по мне, это не тот случай. Неужели вы собираетесь и использовать данный класс в "продакшен" коде таким же макаром, создавая объекты активатором?

Для тестирования интернал членов класса имеется следующий атрибут: *InternalsVisibleTo*, добавив который к конкретной сборке можно сделать "видимыми" интернал члены для тестов.

Comment: 1. Прошу прощения, пропустил `public` перед `TestMe`.
2. Класс с закрытым конструктором -- это дескриптор на некий ресурс, выделение ресурсов должно производиться только через менеджер ресурсов. Вот для этого и нужен.

Решение в одну строчку, спасибо :)

Comment: Не хочу холиварить, но лично мое мнение: подобный подход с "закрытыми классами" не правильный с точки зрения архитектуры и я склоняюсь к тому, что данный подход неверный. Если данный классс нужен ТОЛЬКО для хранения какой либо информации, то в его конструкторе НЕ ДОЛЖНО быть НИКАКОЙ логики и соответсвенно тестированть тут нечего. Возможно я не правильно понял назначение данного класса, но все указывает на проблему в проектировании...

Comment: Согласен, что по-хорошему такой класс стоит тестировать через менеджер ресурсов. Но это очень трудоёмкая задача. Гораздо легче протестировать класс отдельно, пусть и опираясь на внутренние соглашения разработки.

Для большей ясности представьте, что вы тестируете GurbageCollector. Требования к нему очень расплывачатые. И вместо тестирования его самого можно тестировать куда более чётко определённые внутренние подзадачи.

Answer (score 0):

Например, так:

```
B.TestMe(Activator.CreateInstance<A>())
```

А с точки зрения архитектуры - развязывайте объекты через интерфейсы, и таких проблем не будет.